# How to route log out to server in Blazor PWA

Tags: c#, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor PWA which is using the default Microsoft template and it works as expected in the debug locally, but when published the logout link is routed within the local PWA and returns the 404 page rather than directing to the server to do the logout.

I tried putting a cache buster using a datetime like this:

```
$"/identity/account/logout?cacheBust={DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTime()}";
```

But this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is there a way to force a PWA to load a page from the server? Or is there an alternative way to process logout in the PWA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error in the logout link above is that by default the identity links need to have a capital I to work - and so should be :

```
$"/Identity/account/logout?cacheBust={DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTime()}";
```

The more general answer is that these route exceptions are handled in the service-worker.published.js

```
// For all navigation requests, try to serve index.html from cache
// If you need some URLs to be server-rendered, edit the following check to exclude those URLs
const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate'
    && !event.request.url.includes('/connect/')
    && !event.request.url.includes('/Identity/');
```

Any other request can be directed to the server by updating the logic here.